# Jackson is returning duplicate rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jackson

I am trying to return json from these two entity classes.

**Questions.java**

```
@Entity
public class Questions {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private  int id;

@Column(name = "question")
private String question;

@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "param")
private String param;

@Column(name = "maxlength")
private int maxlength;

@Column(name = "dependency")
private String dependency;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "questions",targetEntity = Answers.class, cascade =    CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Answers> answers = new HashSet<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getParam() {
    return param;
}

public void setParam(String param) {
    this.param = param;
}

public int getMaxlength() {
    return maxlength;
}

public void setMaxlength(int maxlength) {
    this.maxlength = maxlength;
}

public String getDependency() {
    return dependency;
}

public Set<Answers> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(Set<Answers> answers) {
    this.answers = new HashSet<>(answers);
    for(Answers answers1:answers){
        answers1.setQuestions(this);
    }
}

public void setDependency(String dependency) {
    this.dependency = dependency;
}
}
```

**Answers.java**

```
@Entity
public class Answers {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "ans_label")
private String ans_label;

@Column(name = "ans_value")
private int ans_value;

@Column(name = "ans_weightage")
private int ans_weightage;

@Column(name = "is_default")
private int is_default;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ques_id", nullable = false)
private Questions questions;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAns_label() {
    return ans_label;
}

public void setAns_label(String ans_label) {
    this.ans_label = ans_label;
}

public int getAns_value() {
    return ans_value;
}

public void setAns_value(int ans_value) {
    this.ans_value = ans_value;
}

public int getAns_weightage() {
    return ans_weightage;
}

public void setAns_weightage(int ans_weightage) {
    this.ans_weightage = ans_weightage;
}

public int getIs_default() {
    return is_default;
}

public void setIs_default(int is_default) {
    this.is_default = is_default;
}

public Questions getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(Questions questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}
}
```

my controller looks like this.

**SaveApiController**

```
@RequestMapping("/getData")
public @ResponseBody List<Questions> getData(){
    List<Questions> questionss=saveApiServices.getQuestions();
    return questionss;
}
```

The json result i am currently getting has bunch of repeated values.

```
[{"id":1,"question":"१. व्यक्तिको पुरा नाम थर?", "type":"input_edittext",   
"description":"","param":"smalltext","maxlength":20,"dependency":"",
"answers": 
[{"id":0,"ans_label":"मुली","ans_value":1,"ans_weightage":0,"is_default":0,
"questions":{"id":1,"question":"१. व्यक्तिको पुरा नाम थर?",
"type":"input_edittext","description":"","param":"smalltext","maxlength":20  
,"dependency":"","answers":[{"id":0,"ans_label":"मुली","ans_value":1,
"ans_weightage":0,"is_default":0,"questions":{"id":1,
"question":"१. व्यक्तिको पुरा नाम थर ?","type":"input_edittext",
"description":"","param":"smalltext","maxlength":20,"dependency":"",
"answers":[{"id":0,"ans_label":"मुली",
"ans_value":1,"ans_weightage":0,"is_default":0,"questions":{"id":1,
"question":"१. व्यक्तिको पुरा नाम थर ?","type":"input_edittext",
"description":"","param":"smalltext","maxlength":20,"dependency":"",
```

my database has only one row inserted. and on my controller there is only one list of questions found. but whenever json output is thrown it repeats a lot of same rows like in the above json sample.

what might be the problems? if you can't find the complete solution can you please suggest me the reason behind the duplication of the same values in json format?

Comment: dude, how could you expect someone read your unformated json..

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is getting in a loop here.  Your `Questions` class has a link to `Answers` and that class refers back to `Questions`.

**Solution**

Mark the `questions` field or the getter in the `Answers` class as `@JsonIgnored`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations

For Jackson to work well, one of the two sides of the relationship should not be serialized, in order to avoid the infite loop that causes your stackoverflow error.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "questions",targetEntity = Answers.class, cascade =    CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Answers> answers = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ques_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Questions questions;
```

Or

If not interested in getting some entity data just use `@JsonIgnore` in any one of the class